# How to solve the differential equation $x^2 \cos{y} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} x \sin{y} =\sin^2y$, given in a competitive exam?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $x^2 \cos{y} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} x \sin{y} =\sin^2y$? I found the problem in a competitive exam.

Comment: It's an inexact differential equation you can make exact with an integrating factor.

Comment: Can you tell me how to find integrating factor??

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html

Comment: This problem can not be solved by the method that you have provided.. I have already tried these methods.

Comment: Show your work/thoughts on the problem, this is not a forum just to plainly ask for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x^2 \cos{y} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} x \sin{y} =\sin^2y$$
The change of function $Y(x)=\cos(y(x))$ leads to a Riccati ODE, then to a second order linear ODE.

[image]

HINT : Solving this second order linear ODE involves Bessel functions.

Comment: Not only Bessel functions. It seems that  the Meijer G function should also appear. This problem is a really difficult one (at least to me). By the way, your approach is really nice. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Claude ! You are right. In fact, this is a bit simpler because, with the particular values of parameters, the Meijer G function reduces to a confluent hypergeometric function. Cheers.

Comment: @ JJacquelin. It is good to know that the monster can simplify !